# Can I use templates/macros/both to wrap each function of a C++ class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Suppose I had this.

```
class A {
  public:
    int f1();
    int f2();
}
```

Is there any way to use templates/macros/both to generate a class that behaves like the following?

```
class GeneratedClass {
  public:
    GeneratedClass(InjectedFunction injected_function) { /* store it */ }
    int f1() {
      injected_function();
      /* forward call to "inner class" and return its value */
    }
    int f2() {
      injected_function()
      /* forward call to "inner class" and return its value */
    }
}
```

Basically I want to be able to generate a class that supports all the functions of a given class, but doing something before it blindly forwards the call.

This class will be created with something like.

```
SomeClassTemplate<A> infected_a(injected_function);
```

Comment: Make `injected_function` a parameter of the constructor.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931456/c-way-of-dependency-injection-templates-or-virtual-methods

Comment: Made changes to the question to be more clear.

Comment: I'm sure I saw an almost identical question a few weeks ago but I can't find it.

Comment: I assume GeneratedClass is supposed to inherit from A? The example code seems to be missing a base class.

Comment: Inherit or composition is fine. The example is what I want the class to behave like. I'll edit the example to be clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, templates cannot generate that code for you automatically. You must write it by hand.

Comment: Thanks. Would there be a workaround to reach something similar with macros then? (I also edited the question subject.)

Comment: @Russell: Just design your program properly in the first place.

Comment: @Tomalak, I'm exploring the power of templates and macros :-)

Comment: @Russell: Nope, macros can't do it either.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want aspect-oriented C++.  [This](http://aspectc.org/fileadmin/publications/aosd-2007-tut-2x2.pdf) link discusses implementing aspect-oriented C++ with pure C++ and also with a language extension.

See also [here](http://www.aspectc.org/) for an implementation.

Aspect-oriented programming is about separation of concerns in a project.  Insertion points are specified where code is inserted.  Sounds like exactly what you want.

Comment: You missed the keyword "generate"

Comment: Everybody else understood it. :)

Comment: @mydogisbox, kind of what I wanted. Does aspect oriented require me to be able to change A's code?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectC%2B%2B  For aspectC++ you define "joinpoints" for your code to be injected.

Comment: "Aspect-oriented programming allows modularizing cross-cutting concerns in a single module, an aspect. Aspects can modify existing classes, but most commonly they provide 'advice' that runs before, after, or around existing functionality."

Comment: @Russell To answer your question more directly, yes, but not manually.  AspectC++ compiles your "aspect" into your code.  From a file perspective they are in different locations and you don't have to change your original code.

Comment: If you're going to change the content of your answer by 100%, please post a new one instead!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Ah, didn't know that was the procedure.